# How to have multiple strings in java?

Tags: java, string

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
String school;
int age;

System.out.print("What is your name? ");
name = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("How old are you? ");
age = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("What school do you attend?" );
school = input.nextLine();

System.out.printf("Your name is %s, you are %d years old and attend %s :) "
        , name, age, name);
```

run:

```
What is your name? Example
How old are you? 21
What school do you attend?Your name is Example, you are 21 years old and attend Example :) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

How do I make string "school"?

Comment: consider reading your code.  Hint: ... name, age, name

Comment: What is the question? (you dont use "school" at the end btw)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
, name, age, name);
```

to

```
, name, age, school);
```

Also, your format `String` doesn't include new-line

```
System.out.printf("Your name is %s, you are %d "
    + "years old and attend %s :)%n", name, age, school);
```

Finally, `nextInt()` leaves a trailing newline so you need to read that

```
System.out.print("What is your name? ");
name = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("How old are you? ");
age = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // <-- age gets the number. There is one newline left.
System.out.print("What school do you attend?" );
school = input.nextLine();
```

The Javadoc for [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) explains the behaviour,

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Answer (score 0):

change Your Code as:

```
age = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
```

And Modify name as Scool in printf()